# Sidenav bar should open from the right instead of from the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I have this simple javascript that opens a sidebar for me but I want it on the right side and not on the left side. Refer to the gif and code below. Anyone knows what I need to do to fix this? Any explanation that you might add would be very much appreciated so I can better understand this code. I tried to fix it myself but I haven't been able to find what exactly determines on which side of the screen it appears.

[image]

```css
.user-menu
{
    padding: 0px 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,'Fira Sans','Droid Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

.user-menu li
{
    padding: 10px;
}

.user-menu:hover
{
    color:white; background:#292929;
    -o-transition:color .25s ease-out, background .25s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:color .25s ease-out, background .25s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color .25s ease-out, background .25s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:color .25s ease-out, background .25s ease-in;
    /* ...and now override with proper CSS property */
    transition:color .25s ease-out, background .25s ease-in;

    background-color: #185886;
}

.button
{
    background: none;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: inherit;
}

.navigationR
{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 6%;
    height: calc(10vh);
    background: #333;
    top: 40px;
    left: -100%;
    transition: .25s;
    display: grid;
}

.navigationR span
{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.navigationR.active
{
    left: 0;
}

.navigationR li
{
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,'Fira Sans','Droid Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.navigationR span:hover
{
    color:white; background:#292929;
    -o-transition:color .25s ease-out, background .25s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:color .25s ease-out, background .25s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color .25s ease-out, background .25s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:color .25s ease-out, background .25s ease-in;
    /* ...and now override with proper CSS property */
    transition:color .25s ease-out, background .25s ease-in;

    background-color: #185886;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigationR">
  <span>
    <form action="/ucp/includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
      <button class="button" type="submit" name="logout-submit">
        <li><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out
      </button>
    </form>
    </li>
  </span>
  <span>
    <form action="/ucp/includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
      <button class="button" type="submit" name="logout-submit">
        <li><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out
      </button>
    </form>
    </li>
  </span>
</ul>
<div class="user-menu">
  <li> <?php echo '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>' . ' ' . $_SESSION["userUid"]; ?> </li></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.user-menu').click(function(){
                        $('.navigationR').toggleClass('active')
                    })
                })
</script>
```

Comment: You have `float: left;` maybe consider changing it to `right` instead

Comment: Hello EGC, I've done that on both of them but it didn't work, they are still on the left side.

Comment: in **HTML file** put `span` and `li` inside the `form` tag and then try

Comment: Your HTML is not valid (you are missing the opening `li` tags). Also, you don't need `form` elements and `submit` buttons just to run some JavaScript like logging in or out. Simple `<button type="button">` elements with `click` events will do.

Comment: @AbhishekPakhare I've put it inside the form tags like this:
```<form action="/ucp/includes/logout.inc.php" method="post"><span> <button class="button" type="submit" name="logout-submit"><li><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out</button></li></span></form>
```
But unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm pretty sure the opening li tags are there? I use a PHP script for logging out, the javascript is just for opening the nav bar, should I still make my buttons like that?

Comment: Upon closer inspection, yes you do have the opening `li` tags, the problem is that they are not closed in the proper place. The closing `li` tags should come right after the text "Log out". And, from what I see you only need to navigate to the appropriate .php page upon a button click. You don't need a `form` to do simple navigation. You aren't collecting any form data, so there's nothing to submit to those .php pages. Frankly, you could just use hyperlinks to do the login and log out and just style the links to look like buttons.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks a lot for the useful advice, I will adjust it right now, also please refer to the image below. https://i.imgur.com/UNZYPUp.png I have since realized the li tags might not be in the right place thanks to Abhishek and I've placed them more appropriately.

Comment: I just updated my comment. The reason I didn't see them is because you don't have the opening/closing tags matched up properly. They should be: `<li><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out</li>`. You can't have a complete element straddling half of another element.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yep, I am aware of that as well. This was just an error on my part, I've since corrected it and haven't found any other instances where I did this. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by putting float: right instead of left on the following CSS classes:

```css
.navigationR {
float: right; 
right: -100%; }

.navigationR li {
float: right; }

.navigationR.active {
right: 0; }

Thanks a lot everyone for pointing it out, simple issues like these take me way too long to discover.
```

Answer (score 0):

Main reason is the following class. needs to be right instead of left.

```
.navigationR.active 
{
     right: 0;
}
```

Also you might need float:right on .navigationR li too.

Comment: I've done so along with adding float:right on .navigationR li and now nothing appears when I try to slide it open.